# Temporary object lifetime issue while creating a span from a vector

Tags: c++, constructor, type-conversion, lifetime

Let's consider the following `proxy` struct that merely keeps track of a reference:

```
template<typename T>
struct proxy
{
    template<typename U> proxy  (const U& u) : t_(u) {}
    auto operator*() const { return t_; }
    const T& t_;
};
```

Now, we can use `proxy` in the `bar` function (here on [godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/cKEhqrxKK)):

```
#include <vector>
#include <span>
#include <numeric>
#include <iostream>

template<typename T>
struct proxy
{
    template<typename U> proxy  (const U& u) : t_(u) {}
    auto operator*() const { return t_; }
    const T& t_;
};

auto bar (proxy<std::span<const int>> p)
{
    // The computation doesn't matter here -> just an example of use of the span contents.
    return std::accumulate ((*p).begin(), (*p).end(), 0);
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v {1,2,3};

    // EXAMPLE 1:
    // The following works well (no error from valgrind).
    std::cout << bar (std::span<const int> {v}) << std::endl;

    // EXAMPLE 2:
    // clang++ -> error: reference member 't_' binds to a temporary object whose lifetime
    // would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object
    std::cout << bar (v) << std::endl;
}
```

In example 1, a call to `bar` with a `std::span` created on the fly from an existing `std::vector` works perfectly.

On the other hand, when I try in example 2 to directly pass the `std::vector` to the function:

- clang++ doesn't compile: `error: reference member 't_' binds to a temporary object whose lifetime would be shorter than the lifetime of the constructed object`
- g++ compiles, the result seems to be ok **but** valgrind is not happy because of use of uninitialized values

**Question 1:** why does clang++ accept example 1 and not example 2 ?

**Question 2:** what is the flaw in the `proxy` struct that makes example 2 fail ?

**Question 3:** it is quite annoying/worrying that g++ (12.3.1) compiles but generates a binary with UB while clang++ (12) seems smarter here by generating an error. Should one consider this is a bug in g++ ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

GCC does not implement [CWG1696](https://wg21.link/CWG1696). This prohibits const reference members binding to temporaries in a *mem-initializer*.

This is prohibited because the lifetime of the temporary would end when the constructor finishes.

Consider what is called when you pass a `std::vector<int>`:

```cpp
template
struct proxy<std::span<const int>> {
    template
    proxy<std::vector<int>>(const std::vector<int>& u) : t_(u) {}
    auto operator*() const { return t_; }
    const std::span<const int>& t_;
};
```

When `t_` is bound to `u`, it would construct a temporary `std::span<const int>` and bind it to the const reference (which is what const references do). This temporary's lifetime would end after returning from the constructor, so now it would be a dangling reference.

That means that `operator*` would copy from a dangling reference, so it would be UB.

If you instead make a constructor taking a `const T&`:

```cpp
template<typename T>
struct proxy
{
    proxy  (const T& u) : t_(u) {}
    auto operator*() const { return t_; }
    const T& t_;
};
```

Then the temporary `std::span<const int>` would be created in `main` and be destroyed at the end of the full expression, which is after the call to `bar` returns.

But at this point you might as well make `bar` take a `const std::span<const int>&` (and for `span` specifically, you might as well take it by value)

Comment: thank you for your answer; I tried to make the constructor take a ```const T&``` but I have an [error](https://godbolt.org/z/4GE649a19). Still, I don't see why the temporary would be then created in the ```main``` (like in example 1).

Comment: You would have to call it `bar({v})` or `bar(proxy<std::span<const int>>(v))`. The constructor for `proxy` is called with the temporary span (created in `main`) to bind to the constructor arg, the constructor for `proxy` never sees a `std::vector<int>` to create a temporary from.

Comment: Ok, I missed the point that the caller had to create the temporary object (like in example 1 after all).